# iptables rules for iscsi initiator

Tags: iptables, iscsi

I need to configure `iptables` on my client (iscsi-initiator). From `tcpdump`, I can see that the server (iscsi target) sends `tcp` from port `3260`.

So I have added following `iptables` rule on my client (where `10.1.212.51` is the iscsi target):

```
-A INPUT -i eth1  -s 10.1.212.51  -p  tcp  -m tcp  --dport 3260  -j ACCEPT
```

but `iscsi` does not work with this rule. Only after I allow all ports, does it work:

```
-A INPUT -i eth1  -s 10.1.212.51  -p  tcp  -m tcp   -j ACCEPT
```

Thus my question is, does `iscsi` need some other port as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the server is sending from port 3260, then you want the client to allow traffic from port 3260.  This is indicated by marking 3260 as the *source* port (sport).
In the rule you posted, you specified 3260 as the *destination* port (dport).

Changing the rule to

```
-A INPUT -i eth1  -s 10.1.212.51  -p  tcp  -m tcp  --sport 3260  -j ACCEPT
```

should work.

Comment: you are right, of course. I should have noticed this myself. How embarrassing. Thanks.